# How to test a functional component that takes a callback function as a prop that updates state via useState hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

Currently trying to test delete functionality in toaster component. Used a callback that will update the state of the parent component. The test fails at the simulate click due to there being no way to access the setter function currently.

```
import React from "react";
import {mount} from "enzyme";
import {CcngToaster, ToasterPosition, ToastStatus} from "./CcngToaster";

 it("Deletes toaster on button click", () => {
        const mockState = [
            {
                id: 0,
                title: "Tea",
                message: "Towel",
                status: ToastStatus.ERROR,
                position: ToasterPosition.TOPRIGHT,
                autoDelete: false,
                autoDeleteTime: 0
            }
        ];
        const wrapper = mount(<CcngToaster toastList={mockState} setToastList={jest.fn()}/>);
        expect(wrapper.find(".toast").length).toBe(1);
        const closeButton = wrapper.find("button");
        closeButton.simulate("click");//Doesn't work since setToastList has no function that will update state
        expect(wrapper.find(".toast").length).toBe(0);//test fails here
        wrapper.unmount();
    });
```

I set up the state via useState and then pass the setter function for toasts to the toaster component

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
    const [toasts, setToasts] = useState<ToastInfo[]>([{
        id: 0,
        title: "Title",
        message: "Message",
        status: ToastStatus.ERROR,
        position: ToasterPosition.BOTTOMRIGHT,
        autoDelete: true,
        autoDeleteTime: 5000
    }]);

    return (
        <div style={{height: "100vh", width: "100vw"}}>
            <CcngToaster toastList={toasts} setToastList={setToasts}/>
        </div>
    );
};
```

The toaster component takes the external state and function for updating it

```
interface InternalToastState {
    [id: number]: {timeoutHandle: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>}
}

interface Props {
    toastList: ToastInfo[];
    setToastList: (newValue: ToastInfo[]) => void;
}

export const CcngToaster: React.FC<Props> = ({toastList, setToastList}: Props) => {
    const [internalState, setInternalState] = useState<InternalToastState>({});

useEffect(() => {
        setInternalState(internalState);
    }, [internalState]);

    const deleteToast = (id: number) => {
        const toastListItem = toastList.findIndex(e => e.id === id);
        toastList.splice(toastListItem, 1);
        setToastList(toastList.slice());

        const internalStateValue = internalState[id];
        if (!internalStateValue) return;
        clearTimeout(internalStateValue.timeoutHandle);
        delete internalState[id];
    };
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test cannot work obviously, as setting `setToastList={jest.fn()}` causes your click to not do anything. You need pass there some function that would re-render your component. Two options that you have:

1. Test your entire `App` component, using state you set up there.
2. Create test wrapper with a mocked state that you would `mount` in a test, something like this:

```
const TestWrapper = () => {
  const [mockState, setMockState] = useState(/*some initial data*/);

  return (<CcngToaster toastList={mockState} setToastList={setMockState}/>
}
```

Then use this component in test:

```
it("Deletes toaster on button click", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<TestWrapper />);
  expect(wrapper.find(".toast").length).toBe(1);
  const closeButton = wrapper.find("button");
  closeButton.simulate("click");
  expect(wrapper.find(".toast").length).toBe(0);//test fails here
  wrapper.unmount();
});
```

That should work. You might optionally create a `prop` in `TestWrapper` to pass initial mocked state from a test and not hard-code inside.

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you so much for the help!